# jquery animate on scroll position

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

Hi i need animate element depend on scroll. My point was set element on top position 1200px but start animate it on 1000px and finish it when it pass 1800px however it start animate on 1400px and finish who knows where

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <section id="first-section"></section>
    <section id="second-section"></section>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#second-section {
    position: relative;
    top: 1200px;
    left: 0;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var top = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (top > 1000 && top < 1800) {
        $("#second-section").stop().animate({
            opacity: "1"
        }, 'slow');
    } else {

        $("#second-section").stop().animate({
            opacity: "0"
        }, 'slow');
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you heard about [skrollr](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/). You can easily animate elements according to scroll position.

Comment: Nope i didnt .. but thanks i am going to try it : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition isn't right. To this purpose your need to get `height` and `position` of element.

See my example

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var winHeight = $(this).height();
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    var elemHeight = $("#first-section").height();
    var elementTop = $("#first-section").position().top; 
     
    if (elementTop < scrollTop + winHeight && scrollTop < elementTop + elemHeight)
        var opacity = 1;
    else
        var opacity = 0;
    
    $("#first-section").stop().animate({
        opacity: opacity
    }, "slow");
});
```

```css
.container {
    height: 2000px;
}

#first-section {
    position: relative;
    top: 1200px;
    left: 0;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <section id="first-section"></section>
</div>
```